# compare two excel worksheet

Tags: excel, file-diffs

I have two excel sheets with the similar header columns and dataset is similar however some times there are some miss-match with their values which I would like to compare with excel formulas or lookup or built in tool. Please advise

Comment: `Please advise` Is too broad.  please specify what you have tried and what does not work.  Adding test data and expected outcome will help us help you.

Comment: actually here my goal is to be able to see columns highlighted where mis-matches are found.

for example 

sheet1  
id         name    email 
111        david   d@email
222        john    j@email
333        smith   s@email

sheet2
111        david   d@email
222        john    h@email ->>>>>>>>>>>
333        smith   s@email

Answer (score 0):

On Sheet1 you can place in column D (example is for row 2 to highlight the row with a mismatch) the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE)=Sheet1!C2,FALSE)
```

This will output TRUE or FALSE depending if the email matches for the unique id. You can adapt using this either for a more complex formula or for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to compare two spreadsheets, Windows comes with a function called Spreadsheet Compare. Just do a search in the task bar and it should come up. It is great if you are looking to compare two separate workbooks. If they are in the same workbook you can copy one into a new workbook then compare them. It will show every discrepancy.